# Using the stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am developing an SMS application and is largely based on the side of data I am using MySQL, but as this is a first experience with stored procedures, triggers and transactions I encounter some problems, here's structure one of the tables that I encounter problem:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cfco_transaction` (
  Id_transac` `int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Cost_paid` float NOT NULL,
  `Phone_number` decimal (9,0) NOT NULL,
  `Money_transac` decimal (8,0) NOT NULL,
  `Total_transac` dual NOT NULL,
  `Transac_status` tinyint (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  `When_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_transac`)
  UNIQUE KEY `phone_number` (` phone_number`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

I would create a procedure that verifies immediately that there is a registration if the cost_paid line money_transac are different from NULL and also that are within cost_paid is greater or equal to 15000 if this is the case makes it update the FALSE to TRUE transac_status line otherwise it is FALSE then renregistre an error in my error tracking table and attempt which the following structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cfco_ticket_errors` (
  Id_error` `int (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Error` `varchar (100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_error`)
  KEY error` `(` error`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 2;
```

This is what I did but it doesn't work

```
 DELIMITER | CREATE PROCEDURE update_status_transact (IN transac_status boolean) begin if (cfco_transaction.cost_paid != NULL) and if (cfco_transaction.money_transac != NULL) update cfco_transaction.transac_status SET 'TRUE' WHERE id_transac= LAST_INSERT_ID; END| DELIMITER;
```

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: the above should be in the body of your question, with additional information such as: current results, expected results, any specific issues you're struggling with